# Sistema faz logout sozinho em qualquer ação

Tags: php, codeigniter

Senhores, No meu sistema Administrativo faço login normal... Porém, qualquer ação dentro do sistema, ele faz logout sozinho... Sem clicar em logout nada... Alguém saberia me descrever se já teve este tipo de problema? Por via das dúvidas, estou colocando o Controller aqui.

## Controller

```
public function verificarLogin(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','valid_email|required|xss_clean|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('senha','Senha','required|xss_clean|trim');
    $ajax = $this->input->get('ajax');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

        if($ajax == true){
            $json = array('result' => false);
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Os dados de acesso estão incorretos.');
            redirect($this->login);
        }
    } 
    else {

        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $senha = $this->input->post('senha');

        $this->load->library('encrypt');   
        $senha = $this->encrypt->sha1($senha);

        $this->db->where('email',$email);
        $this->db->where('senha',$senha);
        $this->db->where('situacao',1);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $usuario = $this->db->get('usuarios')->row();
        if(count($usuario) > 0){
            $dados = array('nome' => $usuario->nome, 'id' => $usuario->idUsuarios,'permissao' => $usuario->permissoes_id , 'logado' => TRUE);
            $this->session->set_userdata($dados);

            if($ajax == true){
                $json = array('result' => true);
                echo json_encode($json);
            }
            else{
                redirect(base_url().'administrar');
            }


        }
        else{


            if($ajax == true){
                $json = array('result' => false);
                echo json_encode($json);
            }
            else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Os dados de acesso estão incorretos.');
                redirect($this->login);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

## Observação

Dentro do sistema eu tenho um controller e um model que gerencia para Adicionar/Editar/Remover dentro da tabela de usuários... talvez tenha alguma coisa a ver com este logout... Se alguém conseguir me ajudar, fico grato.

## Requisição para Logado

```
    if((!$this->session->userdata('session_id')) || (!$this->session->userdata('logado'))){
        redirect('administrar/login');
    }
```

## Resultado do print_r()

```
[userdata] => Array
    (
        [session_id] => 11bd5976ec8ec9d15de1f29277bb4e61
        [ip_address] => 201.10.93.25
        [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36
        [last_activity] => 1436637190
        [user_data] => 
        [nome] => Administrador
        [id] => 1
        [permissao] => 1
        [logado] => 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu já tive esse problema com o `codeigniter` (e você sempre terá problemas com ele) quando configurei a sessão para ser salva como `cookie`.

Troque a opção de `cookie` para `database`. Acredito que o problema seja o `cookie` só comportar uma determinada quantidade de dados.